# Is a subtraction between two integer is an integer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just wonder whether if this is true. Can someone please clear this up ?
Thank You

Comment: Integers: yes; naturals: not!

Answer (score 2):

It is true.  The integers are a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29#Definition) closed under multiplication and addition.  That is, for any two integers $a$ and $b$, we know $a \cdot b$ and $a+b$ are also integers.  Note that, for two integers $x$ and $y$, $x-y$ is just shorthand for $x + (-y)$.

Comment: Make it simpler, it's a group under addition.

Comment: I thought about that, but we might as well kill two birds with one stone and establish that the multiplication of two integers is also an integer.

Comment: very good explanation. Thank You a lot for your answer.